# Python, I want to replace parts of filenames for a group of files

Tags: python, file, rename

I want to write a program that asks you what you want to replace and what to replace it with.

I have a big group of files with different extensions and I want to replace parts of the file names but all of the parts that I want to replace are the same. I want to do it to every file in the folder

So I have files like

```
ABC.txt
gjdABCkg.txt
ABCfg.jpg
ffABCff.exe
```

I would just want to replace ABC with whatever 3 letters I wanted
I'm using python 3.2

I was messing around to see if I could get it to work but nothing I did was working
so here's what I have so far.

```
import os  

directory = input ("Enter your directory")
old = input ("Enter what you want to replace ")
new = input ("Enter what you want to replace it with")
```

Comment: use `str.replace()`, this is your whole code?

Comment: Do you want to do it for *all files* in a directory, or for a *group* of files in a directory?

Comment: In addition to @AshwiniChaudhary, you will also probably need to use `os.listdir` to get a list of the files in the directory.

Comment: If you use *nix, you can give mmv command a shot

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add some things, but here's the basic idea:

```
import os

def rename(path,old,new):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), 
                  os.path.join(path, f.replace(old, new)))
```

EDIT: As noted *@J.F Sebastian* in the comments you can use relative paths from Python 3.3 (at least on a Linux machine).

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.replace):

`os.replace(src, dst, *, src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)` can support specifying `src_dir_fd` and/or `dst_dir_fd` to supply [paths relative to directory descriptors](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#dir-fd).

Comment: You probably want `os.path.join(directory, f)` in there somewhere.

Comment: No, it won't.  The `os.listdir()` function returns just the filename, not the complete path.  The `os.rename()` function requires the complete path.

Comment: @DietrichEpp -- well, I just tried it out on a linux machine, and it seems to work ok...but if the file isn't on the path doesn't work, yes, will edit.

Comment: @root: try running it if `directory` is not current working directory. Unrelated: on Python 3.3 you could use relative paths and overwrite existing files: `os.replace(f, f.replace(old, new), src_dir_fd=dir_fd, dst_dir_fd=dir_fd)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I am guessing that the `src_dir_fd` keyword will only work on systems with support for recent POSIX additions, systems such as Linux (but not OS X, Windows).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The parameters are not implemented on Windows (not sure about OS X). It is not necessary to use them if you want portable way to overwrite destination.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def rename(path,oldstr,newstr):
    for files in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, files), os.path.join(path, files.replace(oldstr, newstr)))
```

using this could easily do your job